# How to find how many file share in azure Storage account using powershell ARM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

I want to file the how many file shares are created in azure storage account using power shell. All my storage accounts are in New Resource Manager Mode.

Thanks 
Amit

Comment: Do you want to find out how many total file shares are there in a storage account or how many of them are created using PowerShell Cmdlets?

Comment: I was looking to find details about file share like count and some other useful details ......

Answer (score 3):

The powershell script below should work for you.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storage-account-name> -StorageAccountKey <storage-account-key>
(Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $ctx).count
```

Comment: For future examples/questions on PowerShell, you might want to check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn806401.aspx and https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-powershell-getting-started/blob/master/AzureFiles.ps1